# Zend 2.0 Apache Web Server Configuration

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, vhosts

I am a newbee to Zend Application , i am using centos 7.0 . I followed the steps of installing Zend Skeleton Application from https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

And i ended up here
https://198.241.15.76/zf2-tutorial/public/

I am unable to how to configure my web server to make my URL look like this as per help guide `zf2-tutorial.localhost`

Also i am unable to understand the below content how to configure the vhost file.

[image]

Please reconsider myself to be a learner.

Comment: Which steps from this documentation have you completed, and which part don't you understand? If you've done all the steps you'd access your site using http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/

Comment: Also, these instructions are aimed at _local development_ - i.e. developing and running an application on your own computer. The address you included in your question appears to be a live server, so there the process would be similar but slightly different.